# python re.findall and re.sub

Tags: python, python-re

My code:

```
import re
print(re.findall(r'(?=(Deportivo))(?!.*\bla\b)','Deportivo coruna'))
print(re.sub(r'(?=(Deportivo))(?!.*\bla\b)','','Deportivo coruna'))
```

I am interested in removing 'Deportivo' if no 'la' in string.

for instance:

```
re.findall(r'(?=(Deportivo))(?!.*\bla\b)','Deportivo coruna')
```

returns ['Deportivo']
and

```
re.findall(r'(?=(Deportivo))(?!.*\bla\b)','Deportivo la coruna')
```

returns []

however,

```
re.sub(r'(?=(Deportivo))(?!.*\bla\b)','','Deportivo coruna')
```

returns 'Deportivo coruna', the string is unchanged. I am confused why, please help.

Comment: Deportivo is a lookahead assertion rather than a match.  Get rid of the `?=(....)`

Comment: That's not a good idea, because then the regex would match if `la` occurs before `deportivo`.

Comment: try replacing your `""` with something else (`"---"`) in the sub to show what's happening.  specifically, *because* this is a lookahead not a match, it's matching the beginning of Deportivo (try adding somethign before Deportivo to prove it)

Comment: @TimPietzcker.  Yeah, you're right.  Is there a solution that handles both ways?  But at least the OP understands what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference in the way `findall` and `sub` work. According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall), `re.findall()` will return the contents of capturing groups, even if the match result itself is the empty string (which it is in your case, since the regex consists entirely of lookahead assertions).

So if you want to remove `Deportivo` from your text if and only if it doesn't  also contain `la`, you could use

```
re.sub(r'^(?!.*\bla\b)(.*?)Deportivo)',r'\1','Deportivo coruna')
```

However, that will only remove the first occurrence, and it's not trivial to change that because you would need unlimited repetition in lookbehind assertions, which Python doesn't support. For the record,

```
re.sub(r'^(?<!\bla\b.*)Deportivo(?!.*\bla\b)','','Deportivo coruna')
```

would do the trick, but that regex won't compile in Python.

So your best bet probably is to do it in two steps. First, check that your string doesn't contain `la`. Then replace all `Deportivo`s with the empty string.